# Bigquery - Extract month as 2 digit

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

How do I extract month as 2 digits from a date field?

My current query:

```
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TransactionDate) as CalendarPeriod,
```

Example:
`2021-07-13` returns `7`

Required Output
`2021-07-13` should return `07`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below instead

```
cast(TransactionDate as string format('MM')) CalendarPeriod
```

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery has a way to pad the leading 0 on dates in months 1-9, using `%m`.

Use this with `FORMAT_DATE()`:

```sql
SELECT FORMAT_DATE("%m",TransactionDate) AS CalendarPeriod
FROM MyTable
```

Data format elements options are listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/format-elements#format_elements_date_time).